# What can't a packet sniffer troubleshoot

Tags: network

This might seem like a really vague question however I am studying a networking course.

One of the many aspects requires the use of a packet sniffer software - in this case I chose Wireshark, which I have used before when trying to find what ports that need to be opened...

One of the questions posed is "What networking troubleshooting tasks will a packet sniffer NOT help with?"

I have basic networking knowledge so if someone with more experience can help me understand this?

Please don't shoot me down, I understand what a packet sniffer can do, which leads to me to seeking help into what can't it do.

Maybe a Network administrator has come across this scenario before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They greatly help with figuring out WHAT is happening at the network level, but they rely on your intelligence for figure out WHY it is happening.

It someone says "I can't access google.com" a packet trace might show you the DNS query, the outbound packet, and a lack of response. But it won't tell you WHY there's no response.

Another practical problem is the amount of data, which gets very large quickly. This is why tools like interactive proxies are often more useful for investigating application layer issues.

Comment: Thank you, kind of helps me understand a bit better the intent of the question. For instance if there is a bottleneck, packet sniffer will expose this but not design flaws, for that you will have to use another tool or expert.

Comment: One more thought, a packet sniffer is of limited use debugging encrypted traffic like SSL

Comment: Thanks so much Paj, I really appreciate your help. It people like you who make a difference to society.